# Set Tablesorter to Descending

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tablesorter

I'm using Tablesorter to display data but it is displaying it in ascending order, I want to display it as descending so the latest addition to the table is always at the top.
Here is my code:

```
            // *** sort options
            headers          : {},         // set sorter, string, empty, locked order, sortInitialOrder, filter, etc.
            ignoreCase       : true,       // ignore case while sorting
            sortForce        : null,       // column(s) first sorted; always applied
            sortList         : [],         // Initial sort order; applied initially; updated when manually sorted
            sortAppend       : null,       // column(s) sorted last; always applied
            sortStable       : false,      // when sorting two rows with exactly the same content, the original sort order is maintained

            sortInitialOrder : 'desc',      // sort direction on first click
            sortLocaleCompare: false,      // replace equivalent character (accented characters)
            sortReset        : false,      // third click on the header will reset column to default - unsorted
            sortRestart      : false,      // restart sort to "sortInitialOrder" when clicking on previously unsorted columns
```

Really unsure what to edit/change so any advice would be really appreciated.

## note

I have removed the original code because it was not actually relevant to what I want to achieve.
This is the sort options part of the js that i believe needs editing.

Comment: I tried changing the order to descending in phpMyAdmin but this only works with existing data, as soon as another row is added it reverts back to ascending. That's why I'm looking to get tablesorter to display the data as descending (latest rows first).

Comment: Ok I think i load the incorrect code in initial question. I just opened jquerytablesorter js.<br/>I looking at below code:

Comment: sortList         : [],         // Initial sort order; applied initially; updated when manually sorted.    I try replacing the [], with 'desc', but the table no longer renders the data correctly

Comment: I replace the brackets in sortList with 'desc', but this does not work

Comment: sortInitialOrder : 'desc',      // sort direction on first click
     I also change sortInitialOrder from 'asc', to 'desc', but this  is on first click whereas I want the table to automatically show descending

Comment: I find solution - sortList : [[0,1]] - 0 is for first column and 1 is for descending. I find the info on: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sortlist

Comment: Can you add the code you are using to add the content to your table.

Comment: Hi Mottie, when I try add code in comment it is not displaying correctly. Besides I find the solution as stated in my last comment. Thanks for the interest.........btw.....tablesorter is awesome:-)

Comment: Thanks! Please add an answer below so we all know you found one. I'll upvote you even!

Answer (score 1):

I find solution, open jquerytablesorter js, then edit as follows:
- sortList : [[0,1]] - 0 is for first column and 1 is for descending. I find the info on: mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sortlist